# Dagger 2: how to change provided dependencies at runtime

Tags: dependency-injection, dagger-2

In order to learn Dagger 2 i decided to rewrite my application but I'm stuck with finding the proper solution for the following problem.

For the purpose of this example let's assume we have an interface called `Mode`:

```
public interface Mode {
    Object1 obj1();

    //some other methods providing objects for app
}
```

and two implementations:
`NormalMode` and `DemoMode`.

Mode is stored in singleton so it could be accessed from anywhere within application.

```
public enum ModeManager {
  INSTANCE,;

  private Mode mode;

  public Mode mode() {
    if (mode == null)
      mode = new NormalMode();
    return mode;
  }

  public void mode(Mode mode) { //to switch modules at runtime
    this.mode = mode;
  }
}
```

The `NormalMode` is switched to `DemoMode` at runtime (let's say, when user clickcs on background couple of times)

```
public void backgroundClicked5Times(){
  ModeManager.INSTANCE.mode(new DemoMode());
  //from now on every object that uses Mode will get Demo implementations, great!
}
```

---

So first I got rid of the singleton and defined Modes as Dagger 2 modules:

```
@Module
public class NormalModeModule {
  @Provides
  public Object1 provideObject1() {
    return new NormalObject1();
  }
}

@Module
public class DemoModeModule {
  @Provides
  public Object1 provideObject1() {
    return new DemoObject1();
  }
}
```

Now in the method `backgroundClicked5Times` instead of dealing with singleton I would like to replace `NormalModeModule` with `DemoModeModule` in DAG so the other classes that need `Object1` would get a `DemoObject1` implementation from now on.

How can I do that in Dagger?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swappable modules with Dagger 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35658488/swappable-modules-with-dagger-2)

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can consider using multibindings?

```
@Module
public class NormalModeModule {
  @Provides
  @IntoMap
  @StringKey("normal")
  public Object1 provideObject1() {
    return new NormalObject1();
  }
}

@Module
public class DemoModeModule {
  @Provides
  @IntoMap
  @StringKey("demo")
  public Object1 provideObject1() {
    return new DemoObject1();
  }
}
```

and when using Mode:

```
@Inject
Map<String, Mode> modes;
//or you perfer lazy initialization:
Map<String, Provider<Mode>> modes;

public void backgroundClicked5Times(){
  ModeManager.INSTANCE.mode(modes.get("demo"));
  //if you are using Provider:
  ModeManager.INSTANCE.mode(modes.get("demo").get());
  //from now on every object that uses Mode will get Demo implementations, great!
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Having experimented with dagger for a while I came up with solution that seems to be working well in my use case.

1. Define class that will hold state information about mode

   ```
   public class Conf {
     public Mode mode;

     public Conf(Mode mode) {
       this.mode = mode;
     }

     public enum Mode {
       NORMAL, DEMO
     }
   }
   ```
2. Provide singleton instance of `Conf` in Module

   ```
   @Module
   public class ConfModule {
     @Provides
     @Singleton
     Conf provideConf() {
       return new Conf(Conf.Mode.NORMAL);
     }
   }
   ```
3. Add module to AppComponent

   ```
   @Singleton
   @Component(modules = {AppModule.class, ConfModule.class})
   public interface AppComponent {
       //...
   }
   ```
4. Define modules that provide different objects based on Mode

   ```
   @Module
   public class Object1Module {

     @Provides
     Object1 provideObject1(Conf conf) {
       if (conf.mode == Conf.Mode.NORMAL)
         return new NormalObject1();
       else
         return new DemoObject1();
     }
   }
   ```
5. To switch mode at runtime simply inject `Conf` object and modify it:

   ```
   public class MyActivity extends Activity {
       @Inject Conf conf;

       //...

       public void backgroundClicked5Times(){
           conf.mode = Conf.Mode.DEMO;

           //if you have dagger objects in this class that depend on Mode
           //execute inject() once more to refresh them
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Seems like a decent way to do this, but this wont work when the provided dependency (that shall be replaced at runtime) is a singleton, will it?

Comment: Yes, if you'd annotate `provideObject1` with `@Singleton` it wouldn't work, but on the other hand it contradicts with the idea in this use case. If you want to replace objects at runtime then you cannot mark such a method with `@Singleton`.
On the other hand you could make `NormalObject1` and `DemoObject1` singletons so the method providing dependencies wouldn't create more than 2 instances.

Comment: That last sentence was the info I needed. Great solution, thx :)

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. But can you please elaborate more about the last comment - "If you have dagger objects in this class that depend on Mode execute inject() once more to refresh them".

Comment: I love this idea, treat module as a configuration

Comment: This is a nice idea. But how do I (//execute inject() once more to refresh them) do this with hilt where I don't explicitly do inject.