# Dagger2 Runtime Polymorphism

Tags: android, dagger-2

How to implement runtime polymorphism by using Dagger2 ?

Say, I have an app which has a RemoteDataRepo with a real webservice as well as a MockDataRepo with some fake data.

1. When the user clicks "signIn" button, the RemoteDataRepo should be loaded and used through out the app.
2. When the user clicks "demo" button, the MockDataRepo should be loaded and used through out the app, which tells the user how the app will look like.

Every one talks about the compile time dependency injection. I really need a runtime solution to polymorphically swap dependencies.

Can any one suggest how to implement this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dagger 2: how to change provided dependencies at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41084333/dagger-2-how-to-change-provided-dependencies-at-runtime)